# Standard way of providing contribution requirements for an r package?

Tags: r

Is there a standard way of providing contribution requirements/instructions for an r package? Things like

- Be sure to run `testthat` tests
- Be sure to run `R CMD check --as-cran`
- Anything other requirements (different packages may have different requirements, e.g. naming conventions)

I have seen some github repos include a file called `CONTRIBUTIONS.md`. But I'm not sure if that's the standard?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard.  You could take a look at packages with lots of authors, and copy what they do.  Here are some that I have installed:

```
 [1] "knitr"         "broom"         "bookdown"     
 [4] "rmarkdown"     "data.table"    "maptools"     
 [7] "shiny"         "xtable"        "StanHeaders"  
[10] "car"           "skimr"         "flexdashboard"
[13] "fortunes"      "forecast"      "markdown"     
[16] "Rttf2pt1"      "rattle"        "cluster"      
[19] "crosstalk"     "foreign"
```

Those are in decreasing order of the number of lines in the `Authors` field in their `DESCRIPTION` file.  These appear to be very successful at encouraging contributions from others, so following what some of them do could be a good plan.